# Android Kotlin - Billing - get productId from In-App purchase

Tags: android, kotlin, android-billing

I'm trying to get the productId from a purchase:

```
private fun queryPurchases(purchases: List<Purchase>){

    for (purchase in purchases) {

        Log.d("pikaboo", purchase.toString())

        when (purchase.purchaseState) {
            Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED -> {

                val purchaseTime = (purchase.purchaseTime / 1000).toInt()

                when (purchase.productId) {
                    "no_ads_in_app_month" -> {

                    }
                    "no_ads_in_app_3_months" -> {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the log:

```
Purchase. Json: {"orderId":"GPA.333.333.333","packageName":"de.bla.foo","productId":"no_ads_in_app_3_months","purchaseTime":1694810217354,"purchaseState":0,"purchaseToken":"xxxxxxxxxxxx","quantity":1,"acknowledged":true}
```

The `productId` in `purchase.productId` is `Unresolved reference`

everything else like `purchase.purchaseTime` `purchase.purchaseState` `purchase.packageName` works.

Why not `purchase.productId`? Is this a bug? How to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure that you have defined the `purchaseId` field in the `Purchase` class correctly? You should be able to see what it actually looks like from the debug log statement in your code. The output you posted is from another log statement.

Comment: I didn't define it, it's from the Billing library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in [Android Developers documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/Purchase#getProducts()) on `Purchase` class, you should be able to get product ids from `getProducts()` method.
Its' return type is `List<String>`.

I am not very familiar with the billing library so I assume purchase can be represented by multiple products. You should probably iterate over the list and place your `when` operator in some kind of loop.